# Controller spec is not incrementing count as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to update my index view with checkboxes. The logic is working as expected but my controller spec in failing and i do not understand why. I am wondering if there might be something wrong with my syntax. The incrementation is working with my feature test but not with the controller spec. The relevant part of the test is as follows:

```
 describe "PUT complete" do 
    it "it archives a diagnostic info report" do 
      diagnostic = FG.create(:diagnostic_info)
      puts DiagnosticInfo.all.size
      expect {
       put :complete, :diagnostic_ids => [diagnostic.id]
       }.to change(DiagnosticInfo.all, :size).by(-1)
      response.should redirect_to(admin_diagnostics_path)
    end
  end
```

The failing test i am receiving is:

```
  1) Admin::DiagnosticsController PUT complete it archives a diagnostic info report
     Failure/Error: put :complete, :diagnostic_ids => [diagnostic.ids]
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `ids' for #<DiagnosticInfo:0x0000000827c678>
     # ./spec/controllers/admin/diagnostics_controller_spec.rb:53:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/controllers/admin/diagnostics_controller_spec.rb:52:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Can you show us your DiagnosticsController?

Comment: The failure error talks about `diagnostic.ids` and your code is `diagnostic.id`... There is a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I amended the test to the following and was therefore able to get it to work.

```
  describe "PUT complete" do 
    it "it archives a diagnostic info report" do 
      diagnostic = FG.create(:diagnostic_info)
      expect {
      put :complete, :diagnostic_ids => [diagnostic.id]
       }.to change(DiagnosticInfo.all, :count).by(-1)
      response.should redirect_to(admin_diagnostics_path)
    end
  end
```